# Android components showcase / visual guide

Tags: android

As a new developer with Android I miss a component showcase or a visual guide like [that for swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/compWin.html) in the documentation.
There is one in someplace?
Normally what I do is use google images with the component name but a visual guide will be nicer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This year Google published [Android Design](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) that has a [Building blocks section](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks) with a showcase of components.

Comment: This returns 404 now

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not exactly what you're looking for, but the *Hello Views* guide should help you a bit with different layouts and some common components: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try out ApiDemo sample from the SDK (you'll have to install them from the Android SDK and AVD manager). Actually it's not only about components but also other features, anyway it's the closest thing to a component showcase I know about.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar resource (in 2019) and found this library in Figma helpful:

https://www.figma.com/file/NMeZfmwo9Nhqi72S0bw3Tn/Android-UI-Kit

Also, the following link is a showcase of the standard components respecting Material Design:

https://materialdesignkit.com/android-gui/