# Is there a graphical overview of all Android GUI element?

Tags: android, user-interface

Sometimes I know that a GUI element looks like but I don't know the name used in Android. With most other GUI the tutorial would have a list of all GUI elements with a nice graphic besides it so you know what it will look like. Does something link this exist for Android.

Comment: wat kind of elements do you mean? Layouts? images? colors?

Comment: this is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573801/android-components-showcase-visual-guide

Comment: @Nanne: I am looking for a list like the one Pontus Gagge has shown. —
@bigstones: Indeed. Sorry for creating a duplicate. But it shows that it is a needed info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not entirely up to date, but [this list is useful](https://web.archive.org/web/20150206034306/http://droiddraw.org/widgetguide.html).

Comment: My datepicker doesn't look anything like the one on that list?

Comment: Not up to date, nor complete, but a starter.

Comment: Yes, a nice starter. It up-to-date and complete then it is exactly what I was looking for. Even better then what I was looking for as it has the XML info as well.

Comment: Link no longer works :/

Comment: Waybacked it. It's even less up to date now...

Answer (score 5):

This is not exactly what you asked, but I think it might help:

1. [Pencil Homepage](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx) (mockups)
2. [Android Draw](http://www.droiddraw.org/androiddraw.html) (android application to see your UI on a real device)
3. [PSD file](http://www.matcheck.cz/androidguipsd/)  (sample elements of the UI)
4. [Several utilities](http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/)

Also, remember that in the world of android almost **every brand and every carrier change things a little bit to make it "better"**. This means that many UI elements may look different or have different colors in many devices. Also remember that different android versions (1.5, 1.6, 2.1, 2.2...) also have some differences.